# Eclipse: how to show the information about a PHP function?

Tags: php, eclipse

when i go with the mouse pointer on the function it doesn't show the location, class...

i have this problem in one of my projects. All is executed ok so the functions are there :).

Build id: 20090920-1017

Any idea?

Javi

Comment: Does it still show up when your cursor is on the function and you press F2 ?

Comment: Hi, when the cursor is on the function and i press F2 nothing appears.

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem. I had a project where i was able to use this, but not in my other project. After looking around I found the reason, my new project was not set as a php project, and hence I was not getting the function locations etc. Here is what I did to fix the problem.

1. In eclipse, on your project, do RMB (right mouse button click).
2. Look for "Configure" menu. Click on it.
3. One of the options given to you will be "Add PHP support...", click on that.

And VOILA.. you have the lovely hover hyper link working for your project all over again.

Answer (score 0):

You should restore Hovers to default.

See your Eclipse Preferences:

Java -> Editor -> Hovers

Click on "Restore Defaults"

Comment: sorry, i forgot to say im using eclipse pdt.

Answer (score 0):

It's either in

- Java->Editor->Content-Assist->Advanced select PDE API Tools proposals
- Java -> Editor -> Hovers (as described before) Click on "Restore Defaults"
- PHP -> Editor -> Hovers
- also check settings in PHP -> Editor -> Content Assist

If all this didn't work perhaps start eclipse with -clean parameter or reinstall?
hope this helps and is not to late